# Get POST data in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to get the POST data in Webdriver? If so, how do you do it?
I can hardly find anything.
I know I could do it manually by reading the values of the forms I submit, but I'd like to make a reusable method, where I need the POST data.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

We can make better usage of Tools like 
`YSlow, Firebug , ShowSlow` to read the http headers that are sent and recieved by browser

We had tried only for firefox and it works fine on our end

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) it should get you the POST data using WebDriver